# Limitation of onClick Functions or modals?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am certain this is something really simple. The basic gist is that I have a grid of 8 images, once you hover on an image a blurb is given and a button to provide more info. click the button and a modal pops up.

This all works perfectly on the first 5 elements, however it fails thereafter.

[Full demo is on CodePen](https://codepen.io/matbowden/pen/gOPPKpb)

Shortened Version of the code is as follows: 
All Buttons are as below:

```
HTML

<button id="myBtn" class="myBtn btn">Read More</button>
```

All Modals are set out as below:

```
HTML       
<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal2-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>   
                <p>Modal 2 content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is repeated 8 times for each modal. 
The JS is as below:

```
JS
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");


btn[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "block";
}

btn[1].onclick = function() {
    modal[1].style.display = "block";
}

btn[2].onclick = function() {
    modal[2].style.display = "block";
}

btn[3].onclick = function() {
    modal[3].style.display = "block";
}

btn[4].onclick = function() {
    modal[4].style.display = "block";
}

btn[5].onclick = function() {
    modal[5].style.display = "block";
}

btn[6].onclick = function() {
    modal[6].style.display = "block";
}

btn[7].onclick = function() {
    modal[7].style.display = "block";
}


span[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "none";
}

span[1].onclick = function() {
    modal[1].style.display = "none";
}
span[2].onclick = function() {
    modal[2].style.display = "none";
}
span[3].onclick = function() {
    modal[3].style.display = "none";
}
span[4].onclick = function() {
    modal[4].style.display = "none";
}
span[5].onclick = function() {
    modal[5].style.display = "none";
}
span[6].onclick = function() {
    modal[6].style.display = "none";
}
span[7].onclick = function() {
    modal[7].style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

This functions fine for the first 5 button clicks, however the final 3 won't appear upon clicking the button.

However, if you subsequently click one of the first 5 buttons - the original modal appears on-top of the modal from the button you just clicked.

Is there a limitation on successive onClick scripts? or is there something in jQuery not allowing for more than 5 modals - or is this a simple coding error I have made (which is probably the most likely!)

I am at a loss as to what is going on, so any help would be great. 
& before anyone suggests it - I don't want to use bootstrap (JS) as it will conflict with other code on my site.

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to let you know, your code readability would go up exponentially if you just looped through the collection of elements and added the event handlers instead of explicitly accessing them one at a time.

Comment: Also, use the inspector from your browser's dev tools. You might have spotted the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing `</div>` tag for `myModal5`. Then the browser nests the other modals inside `myModal5` and that's why the don't show

```
<!-- Modal 5 -->
<div id="myModal5" class="modal">
    <div class="modal5-content">
        <span class="close">×</span>
        <h3> Targeting</h3>
        <div class="divider divider-end div1 ldiv" data-aos="fade-right">
            <p>Through audience development we can tailor keyword groups, adverts and landing pages to suit not only the
                consumers search term, but your marketing message.</p>
            <p>Through this direct targeting we can ensure we optimise what we present to individual search, ensuring we
                present the right message at the right time, all of the time.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- <= missing this tag here -->
```

Comment: If only you knew how much time I had spent running through this code and checking for exactly that! - Thank you for your assistance. I knew it would be user error!

Comment: It happens sometimes :) The issue was visible immediately in devtools